# Should I play Enemy Unknown before Enemy Within?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown, xcom-enemy-within

I bought on Steam both XCOM Enemy Unknown and its expansion Enemy Within. When I launch the game it lets me choose if I want to play Enemy Unknown or Enemy Within.

There is any reason to play without the expansion first?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You should play Enemy Within.

The expansion simply adds new upgrades, options, mission types, etc. to the base game; the basic story progression does not change. Thus, there's no compelling reason to play Enemy Unknown if you own Enemy Within, unless you *really* don't like something it adds to the game.

Comment: Only real reason to start with enemy unknown is the lower complexity if you feel uncomfortable with strategy games

Comment: Even then, most of the Enemy Within stuff is optional, and also earned over time, like Gene Mods/MEC Troopers. I can definitely see EXALT being a pain for someone who's not as good at such games, though.

Comment: I started playing Enemy Unknown recently and it is my first TBS. Coming from other games, where DLC introduces new story elements and places/worlds, I started with EU instead of EW. Wish I had seen this answer when I started playing EU.